# How to set lock mode when fetching with EntityValueResolver

Tags: php, symfony, controller, locking, entity

In a Symfony application you can use the EntityValueResolver to automatically fetch an entity when declaring the controller route.

How can one set a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock mode for this fetch?

This very basic controller successfully fetch the Product entity but it applies no lock.

```
#[Route('/product/{id}')]
public function show(#[MapEntity] Product $product): Response
{
  // use the Product!
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to define lock in EntityValueResolver as a function argument. You can do it with Request Object in the argument and apply the lock inside function.

```
$entity = $this->em->find(Product::class, $id);
// use the product for some read-only code

// Later, Need to update the product
$this->em->lock($entity, LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

$entity->setStock($entity->getStock() - 1);
$this->em->flush();
```

Comment: Ok thanks, sure I know I can, I just was wondering if I can also achieve it within the parameter definition.